# Syntax error for Insert value statement

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, insert

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_item_cost (iItemId INTEGER, fNewcost NUMBER) AS 
  fCurCost NUMBER(10,2);
  missing_cost EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
  SELECT item_cost 
  INTO fCurCost 
  FROM pitem
  WHERE item_id = iItemId;

  IF fCurCost IS NULL THEN
    RAISE missing_cost;
  ELSE
    UPDATE pitem 
    SET item_cost = fNewCost
    WHERE item_id = iItemId;
  END IF;

  COMMIT;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN no_data_found THEN
    INSERT INTO pitem_audit
    VALUES (iItemId, 'Invalid Item identifier.');
COMMIT;
  WHEN missing_cost THEN
    INSERT INTO pitem_audit
    VALUES (iItemId, 'Null value replaced by original cost of '||TO_CHAR(fCurCost));
    COMMIT;
  WHEN too_many_rows THEN
    INSERT INTO pitem_audit
    VALUES (iItemId, 'More than one row for this item: both rows deleted, new row inserted');
    COMMIT;
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    ROLLBACK;
    INSERT INTO pitem_audit
    VALUES (iItemId, 'Miscellaneous error.');
    COMMIT; 
END update_item_cost;
/
```

--My question is for the syntax on the block that handles the exception for missing_cost.
My message string is only displaying 'Null value replaced by original cost of '...I need it to include the fCurCost but for some reason its not displaying...I keep getting a warning saying: procedure created with compilation errors.--

--ALSO for the TOO_MANY_ROWS exception handler...how would I write the code to delete multiple rows??? I've tried the:

```
DELETE FROM pitem
WHERE item_id NOT IN(SELECT MAX(item_id) 
                     FROM pitem
                     GROUP BY item_id, item_cost);
```

--but to no avail...--

Answer (score 0):

The `values` statement wants constants.  Use `insert . . . select` instead:

```
WHEN missing_cost THEN
    INSERT INTO pitem_audit
        select iItemId, 'Null value replaced by original cost of '||TO_CHAR(fCurCost));
    COMMIT;
```

For the second question:

If you want to delete all but the row with the highest price:

```
DELETE FROM pitem
where cost < (select Max(item_cost)
              FROM pitem
              group by item_id
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

1) The exception MISSING_COST is raised whenever fCurCost is null therefore, when you insert its value into pitem_audit it will always be NULL.

2) If you were trying to delete all the rows but the one with the highest item_id, you should try something like this:

```
DELETE FROM pitem
WHERE item_id NOT IN(SELECT MAX(item_id) 
                     FROM pitem);
```

You were grouping by item_id and item_cost, this means that you were selecting the highest item_id among the rows with teh same item_id and item_cost. If item_id is an unique identifier, the subquery would return all the rows in the table since every item_id would be the highest value in its group.